# Seg fault when assigning an instantiated struct?

Tags: c, pointers

```
struct queens_arg {
  int board[64]; 
  int focus_idx;
};

struct queens_arg *args;
(*args).focus_idx = 0;
```

The code is as the following. I get a seg fault (debugged) to occur on setting `focus_idx = 0`. Why is this happening? How can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating a pointer to a `struct queens_arg`, but you're not initializing it to point anywhere.  Consequently, when you write

```
(*args).focus_idx = 0;
```

You're following a garbage pointer, causing the segfault at runtime.

To fix this, make sure that you set up the pointer to point somewhere.  Here's how you can have it point to dynamically-allocated memory:

```
struct queens_arg* args = malloc(sizeof (struct queens_arg));
```

On a related note, you don't need to write

```
(*args).focus_idx = 0;
```

You can instead use this shorthand:

```
args->focus_idx = 0;
```

It means exactly the same thing, but is a bit easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

This occurs because you used a pointer, yet you didn't allocate anything. Hence you are writing into memory that is not yours.

You should first allocate `args` as follows:

```
struct queens_arg *args = malloc(sizeof(struct queens_arg));
```

Then you should check if `args != NULL`. If not, you can write to the memory you just allocated, using:

```
args->focus_idx = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You've only declared a pointer to a `queens_arg` struct, no struct actually exists.